# Not able to establish connection with Progress Database using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, openedge, progress-db

I am getting the following exception :-

```
java.sql.SQLException: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Access denied(Authorisation failed)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.client.ddd.aw(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.client.ddd.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.OpenEdgeImplConnection.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.BaseConnection.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.BaseConnection.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.BaseConnection.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.BaseConnection.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.BaseDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.ncr.sj250216.JdbcTest.main(JdbcTest.java:18)
```

There is no compile time error in my code, i am using the right jars as referenced libraries.

```
      package com.ncr.sj250216;
      import java.sql.*;
      public class JdbcTest 
      {
          public static String       
 URL="jdbc:datadirect:openedge://sun3899.daytonoh.ncr.com:28409;DatabaseName=dispatch";
    public static String username="CSMSRUP";
    public static String password=null;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

     try
      {

       Class.forName ("com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.OpenEdgeDriver");
       System.out.println("Driver loaded");
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,username,password);
       System.out.println("Connected");
       Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
       System.out.println("Statement created");
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select remark from pub.dupdate_remarks");
       System.out.println("ResultSet : \n");
       while (rs.next())
       {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
       System.out.println("AFTER CRUISING THROUGH THE RESULT SET");
       rs.close();
       stmt.close();
       conn.close();
      }
      catch (Exception x) 
      {
          x.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Access denied` and `Authorization failed` mean that you either have the wrong userid & password or you are attempting to connect to the wrong db.

If you have access to the server that the db runs on you can test your credentials using Progress' `sqlexp` command line tool:

```
sqlexp -user userName -password passWord -db dnName -S servicePort
```

Or you could use any popular Windows based SQL querying tool to try the connection...

Comment: The issue that i am facing now is that i am able to connect if the password is not null but when the DBA sets the password as null , i am unable to make the connection.

Comment: Is there a way to access the DB with null as the password ?

Comment: Try "" instead of the word null.  Or do not specify the -password argument.  IOW: sqlexp -user UserName -db dbName -S portNum